# lsilogic did the trick for virtualbox to get rid of hardware detection issue how to do it for real system?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

I wanted to try an old linux distribution , so i installed it on virtualbox got an error `no device detected` while partitioning my disk foun a solution to change controller type to `lsilogic` . Now I have the exact same issue with real hardware how to get it rid of it? any changes in Bios or any other solution ?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of storage controller does your real system have, then? (And what controllers does the Linux distribution support?)

Comment: =@user1686 it's an old system `( CMOS setup 1984-2008)` in Bios I have `sata AHCI mode`   and `Sata 0-3 native mode` and trying to install `fedora core 4`

Comment: You're missing a driver. To get an answer, please specify for starters the computer model, the OS you're installing and how, the hard disk model and where is it connected.